# Combining ulem and seqsplit results in error

Tags: texlive, ulem, seqsplit

The following code works fine when running `pdflatex` in version `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)`, but fails in version `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian)`:

```tex
\documentclass[english, paper=a4, fontsize=10pt, DIN]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{ulem}


\begin{document}
\sout{\seqsplit{Sometext}}
\end{document}
```

This is what happens:

```bash
pdflatex minimap.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./minimal.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize10pt.clo)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/seqsplit/seqsplit.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [english,DIN].

(./minimal.aux)
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\UL@stop ...z@ \else \UL@putbox \fi \else \egroup 
                                                  \egroup \UL@putbox \fi \if...
l.7 \sout{\seqsplit{Sometext}}
                              
?
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Tho overall goal is to have long text that wrap if there is not enough space and this text is striked through.

Comment: With `pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021)` I don't get any errors. So maybe just update your packages or package distribution. The keywords `english,DIN` are unknown, as it is said in the warning.

Comment: To the contrary, the code works with TL 2021, but fails with TL 2020 (fully update before final freeze). It works with TL 2019 or older.